# SpriteKit: how to find the position at which two sprites or physics bodies contact

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have created two sprites and handled their contact. I want to create a new sprite at the position that the two bodies come into contact. How can I get the position of one of the contacted sprites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the `SKPhysicsContact`class. [(See here)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsContact/index.html)

> To receive contact messages, read the physicsWorld property of an SKScene object you are interested in, and assign its contactDelegate property to point to an object that implements the SKPhysicsContactDelegate protocol. Then, for each physics body in your scene, set the categoryBitMask and contactTestBitMask properties to define which interactions should generate contact messages.

On the generated SKPhysicsContact property you can read the `contactPoint` variable.